# join 2 tables and check some information

Tags: laravel

I am having this simple query in laravel 8:

```
Company::select('id', 'name')->get()
```

to retrieve all the companies for using them in a select.

I have another model `Contracts` which contains `user_id` and `company_id`. Each contract is done by a user and is assigned to a company.

How can I write the join to get me all the Companies (like before) but with another field extra `hasLastInsertedData` (true or false)

This field should tell me that if the user authenticated has used this company for creating a contract.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a left join to join the contracts table and then use a condition to check if the user has created a contract with the company.

```
$userId = auth()->user()->id;

$companies = Company::leftJoin('contracts', function ($join) use ($userId) {
    $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'contracts.company_id')
         ->where('contracts.user_id', '=', $userId);
})
->select('companies.id', 'companies.name', DB::raw('(contracts.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS hasLastInsertedData'))
->get();
```

Comment: in order to work properly (to avoid duplicate entries) I had to use this and group by id: ```->select(DB::raw('any_value(companies.id) as id'), DB::raw('any_value(companies.name) as name'), DB::raw('any_value(contracts.user_id IS NOT NULL) as hasLastInsertedData')->groupBy('companies.id')```